# Control Initialization-Complete Indication?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, vb6, controls

Writing a custom-control (inherits Control and *not* UserControl).

Within control's constructor, control property-values are still not valid (e.g. Location, Height, Width, Text, etc...).
Property setters are called only after constructor-function has returned.

Consider the point in time on which control-object initialization has been complete, i.e. right after values of all properties have been initially set, and object is ready-for-use (i.e. to be drawn for the 1st time). Can this point-in-time be intercepted during runtime?
Is there some sort of a "Ready" or "Initialization-Complete" control-event, or some other indication which could intercepted at runtime, **before control-surface is drawn for the 1st time**, i.e. **before the 'OnPaint' event-handler is invoked for the 1st time**?

Thanks much.

**Using Winforms over VB2005**.

Comment: Hi,  Perhaps more people will be willing to help if you accept an answer to a few of your questions.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't aware of the importance of "accept". I merely thanked by a comment to the people who helped. Shall correct that, BL"N. Thanks for the note.

Comment: Why can't you put a call in OnPaint, and ensure it's only called once?

Comment: I can, ofcourse, do that, but it doesn't seem as a correct coding approach. Consider a graphical control refreshing its surface 100 times per second (or more). It would perform the "Is First Paint" boolean-check every time, redundantly. Although runtime-consumption-cost would not be too high (100 boolean checks per second), it seems like a lacking approach, or in other words: There must be a better "cleaner" way to do it :-)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at  [Control Inspector](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3317/ControlInspector-monitor-Windows-Forms-events-as-t)  It's a cool little utility to show you the order of events for a control.  Event the Screenshot in the article may answer your question.

Comment: Surely a neat application. Hope I'll find an answer using it... Thanks.

Comment: +1 for the application, but an answer was still not found. Thanks again for the kind will.